# RestEasy: WARN NoClassDefFoundError DocumentProvider

Tags: java, resteasy

I'm using the RestEasy Client Framework and have a `WARN` with the following code:

```
RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());

// [WARN] org.jboss.resteasy.logging.impl.Log4jLogger-103: NoClassDefFoundError:
//   Unable to load builtin provider:     
//   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider
```

According to [GrepCode](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/2.3.1.GA/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/DocumentProvider.java#DocumentProvider) this class should be in `resteasy-jaxrs` module. It's only a warning, but I have found only a few few hints to this on Google and wonder if I should ignore it or find a solution, since it is only a warning and not a CNFE. The code followings works without problems.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency> 
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this warning try this:

```
public class SomeClass
{       
  static {ResteasyProviderFactory.setRegisterBuiltinByDefault(false);}

  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

**Update** According to http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Migration_from_older_versions.html the method call `RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());` is not needed anymore!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!  When providing an answer, it is _always_ a good idea to provide supporting links for your answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to SO! This targets me to http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Migration_from_older_versions.html where it is mentioned that the call of `RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance())` is not needed anymore!